# DF column with only numeric values

Tags: python, pandas

I have DF with two columns. Both contains numeric values together with symbols and letters.

I need to create two new columns with numbers only. Nothing can be dropped or deleted- it is important to keep the initial order the same.

I tried

```
> df["PRIMARY"]=df['PRIMARY PHONE'].filter(i for i in s if i.isdigit())
```

It does not work as initially my column is obj.
I need to get (as an example) from PL73)67 only 7367 for each cell

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `map`:

```py
def extract_num(s):
    return "".join(x for x in str(s) if x.isdigit())

df["PRIMARY"] = df["PRIMARY PHONE"].map(extract_num)
```

Comment: yes, looks like a possible solution, but gives a mistake int object is not iterablec

Comment: Add `str` in the function (I have updated my answer)

Comment: This would be significantly slower for mid-large datasets. @MayyaLihovodov

Comment: Was very fast on 100+ K rows

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything other than digits and convert string to integer

```
df['PRIMARY'] = pd.to_numeric(
    df['PRIMARY PHONE'].str.replace('[^\d]', '', regex=True),
    errors='coerce'
)
```

Comment: Can not convert float nan to integer

Comment: @MayyaLihovodov Fixed it.